# Issues in Error handling sub in VB Script

Tags: vbscript

I have written an error handling sub in my vb script

```
errorNumber = DoAllWork
Sub ErrorHandling (Number, Description, i)
If Number <> 0 Then
   WriteLogFileLine logfile, "Error No : " & Number & " - " & Description & " has occurred !"
Else
   WriteLogFileLine logfile, "Success copying files as Err.Number : " & Err.Number & "Total " & i & " files were copied ! " & vbcrlf
End If
Err.Clear
End Sub
```

And I am calling it in my vb script like this

```
Function DoAllWork
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Do Until CopyFiles.AtEndOfStream
        line = CopyFiles.ReadLine
        For Each line In CopyFiles 
            If objFSO.GetFolder(line).Files.Count <> 0 then
                WriteLogFileLine logfile, "Copying files FromLocation " & Chr(34) & line & Chr(34) & " to ToLocation " & Chr(34) & ToLocation & Chr(34)
            Else
                WriteLogFileLine logfile, "No files present in the folder " & Chr(34) & line & Chr(34) & vbcrlf
            End if
            i=0
            For Each File In objFSO.GetFolder(line).Files 
                objFSO.GetFile(File).Copy ToLocation & "\" & objFSO.GetFileName(File),True 
                i=i+1
            Next
            ErrorHandling Err.Number, Err.Description, i
        Next
    Loop
End Function
```

Now the log file which is getting created has this error messages logged in it even though the files has got copied successfully. Can someone please suggest what is wrong with this error handling technique ??

```
2015-12-15 15:03:47 - Copying files FromLocation "\\srv10219\archive\Article\20151116_073104" to ToLocation "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\ICCdata\Article"
2015-12-15 15:03:47 - Error No : 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method has occurred !
```

when I place this error handling directly after the `File.copy` statement, it gives me such log..

```
2015-12-15 16:31:55 - Error No : 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method has occurred !
2015-12-15 16:31:55 - Success copying files as Err.Number : 0
2015-12-15 16:31:55 - Total 2 files were copied !
```

that means for the first file which is being copied it throws an error and for the second one it gives success even though both the files has been copied successfully

Comment: Why the `objFSO.GetFile(File).Copy`? You already have the `File` object reference from the `For Each` loop you don't need to instantiate it again. Should be able to do `File.Copy` instead.

Comment: Also would have the `ErrorHandling` inside the `objFSO.GetFolder(line).Files` `For Each` loop and output the `i` variable in the error to give better feedback about where the error occurs.

Comment: @Lankymart - Thanks for ur input. I am new to VB script. I will correct the copy command. The reason for not having the errorhandling inside the objFSO.GetFolder(line).Files loop is , there are thousands of files being copied, I don't want so many lines written to the log everytime.

Comment: In that case you probably want `If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For` directly after the `File.Copy` to halt the `For Each` loop and allow you to report what iteration triggered the error.

Comment: @Lankymart - when I place this error handling directly after the `File.copy` statement, it gives me such log.. `2015-12-15 16:31:55 - Error No : 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method has occurred !
2015-12-15 16:31:55 - Success copying files as Err.Number : 0

2015-12-15 16:31:55 - Total 2 files were copied !`   that means for the first file which is being copied it throws an error and for the second one it gives success even though both the files has been copied successfully.

Comment: Can You add code and log updates to the question. Helps with readability and keeps the question up to date.

Comment: Ideally you need to show the script changes you have made as well, also noticed that the output of your log doesn't match what would be generated in `Sub ErrorHandling ()` have you changed it slightly?

Comment: @Jake - Thanks for the above script. Just one question here. Do I have to write the Err.Clear before calling the sub everytime inside the script or I can do that inside the sub and not required to mention it everytime inside the main script ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98090/discussion-between-pals-and-lankymart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this to do pretty much what you asked. What the script needed to do was take a folder and its contents that was dropped into a directory, and then copy the contents to a new folder formatted correctly where there was a poller that picked up the files and entered them in our system. I needed the script to quit on any error, especially for the last thing to do. That was to delete the folder from the source directory, but I had to make sure it got copied correctly. (You could clear the error and continue as well.)

So after each important line like a folder create or a file copy I did this check. This worked for me to do error handling. Passing the Err object itself is the best way to go.

```
Set FolderCreate = FSO.CreateFolder(PreStagingDirectory + "\" + FolderCreateName)
ReportErrors Err,"Error creating folder: " + PreStagingDirectory + "\" + FolderCreateName


FSO.CopyFile objFile.Path, FolderCreate.Path + "\", true
ReportErrors Err,"Error copying file: " + objFile.Path + " to location: " + FolderCreate.Path


Sub ReportErrors(ErrorObject, strExtraInformation)

    'This will log any errors if they happen and the script will then quit
    If ErrorObject.Number <> 0 Then
        OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " Error Number: " & ErrorObject.Number)
        OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " Error (Hex): " & Hex(ErrorObject.Number))
        OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " Source: " &  ErrorObject.Source)
        OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " Description: " &  ErrorObject.Description)
        OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " Other Information: " + strExtraInformation)
        OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " Script is quitting due to the Error Condition.")
        wscript.quit
    End If

End Sub
```

I have also done code like this. In this case I needed to catch if null was returned from a SQL query to the database. If null was returned and I try to cast the value, it caused an error.

To answer the question of should you check for errors in a sub and clear them, or check for errors all through your script really depends what you need to accomplish.

First I have to say error handling in vbscipt just sucks. Using 'On Error Resume Next', is absolutely needed but be careful where you place it. I found it is not best to place it in main, at the top, just within each function. Most important is to remember the scope, if you put it in a function, you catch the error there, and can handle it. If you only have it at as the first line of your script, you can only handle an error in main. It is needed in main, sometimes.

Also to debug any vbscript, comment out any call to that, or you will never know the problem.

```
    ExecutionString = "select Sum(cast(Frame_Count as int)) from Sop_Instance_T"
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(ExecutionString)  


    TotalFrames = cdbl(objRecordSet(0))


    'In case null is returned catch the exception
    'that happens on the above line
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        TotalFrames = 0
        Err.Clear ()
    End If
```